# Frequent errors submitting edits

Tags: bug

I have recently (in the last month or so) noticed a very uncomfortable rate of error submitting edits to my posts or comments. The error message is a red

> "An error occurred submitting the edit"

Even as I write this, a persistent error has prevented me from uploading a screenshot of one of the errors!

Along the line, I thought something was wrong with my Chrome installation, until I realized that switching to Firefox did not fare better.

Is there something I might be missing?

Comment: I personally don't recall having experienced any errors over the last "month or so." Is your Internet connection generally stable? Is it just on StackOverflow, or does it happen on other StackExchange communities you're active in?

Comment: I've had several of these in the last few hours, more than for some weeks beforehand. They seem to come and go.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ My internet connection is generally stable, and, unfortunately, apart from SO, I haven't been very active elsewhere on SE recently, therefore I cannot be sure.

Comment: I have not had any issues as of late. I would log when the issues occur and post them here. It could help track down the issue.

Comment: could you capture a the HTTP causing this error, using something like fiddler?

Comment: @Liam: Phew! I had never used anything fiddler before (beyond firebug and co), but I have just completed intallation, added a Filter for stackoverflow.com. The first edit I performed has gone without error. Problem is, I'm not 100% sure of what to look out for in the http (when next the error occurs)

Comment: If it fails I'd just post the HTTP request/response, what response code do you get (HTTP 500, 404, etc?)

Comment: Do you have any webfiltering where you are trying to do this? Some appliances can cache your authentication and it it expires before you submit your changes then this could happen.

Comment: @Matt: That makes sense, given the issues mentioned about uploading images. Imgur is blocked at my workplace, for example, which sometimes leads to errors.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ By design my filter can allow people in for a certain amount of time or need to authenticate but later re-authenticate. It _sometimes_ works which lead me to this conclusion. I have this issue with chat site all the time. I guess another question would be can you reproduce this at another network location.

Comment: @Liam You don't. It's implemented via AJAX and all the browser gets is a JavaScript event saying 'error'.

Answer (score 1):

One of two things have happened when I run into this issue. 1) My internet connection has crashed, or 2) The question/answer that I was trying to edit was deleted when I was in the process of editing. It also might be an issue or slowness with the SO servers.

Comment: Neither of these two things has happened to me most of the time I run into this issue. I've also been getting frequently recently while voting.

Comment: It could be the servers.

Comment: Of course it's the servers, that's the reason for the question.